# How to determine the original type of object variable

Tags: java, validation, object, types

I am using an ArrayList Of Object which contains  Data . I am using the following code

```
 if(SQL2000NumericDataTypes.contains(colDataType.toLowerCase())) 
  {
        if ((data.getClass().equals(String.class)) || (data.getClass().equals(char.class)) || (data.getClass().equals(Boolean.class)) )
   {
      message="The String Inputed"+dataStr + "is in the worng Data Type and Cannot Be Saved";
      returnBool=true;
      objLst1D=null;
      objLst1D=new ArrayList<Object>();

      objLst1D.add(message);
      objLst1D.add(returnBool);
      objLst2D.add(objLst1D);
   }

  }
```

where data  is of the object type and is drawn from code

```
list.get(i).get(j).get(k)
```

and the def for list is as follows

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>> data_header_mapper;
```

The data_header_mapper contains the map of col names and respective data values.

Problem is that

```
data.getClass()
```

in every case returns String , for e.g. for int,float and date values. Please guide how to check it

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106336/how-do-i-find-out-what-type-each-object-is-in-a-arraylistobject

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Related to the OP's previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458752/how-to-populate-and-access-any-element-of-3-dimensional-array-list

Comment: Note that `data.getClass().equals(char.class)` could never possibly return `true` since `char` is a primitive - you probably meant to use `Character.class`.

Comment: All the mentioned types (String, Boolean, Char) could be represented as Strings in Java, for example if you get these field from an Oracle DB. Have you tried this with a number field for example?